# Extra electric strike protection for access control system

Tags: power-supply, control, circuit-protection, ptc

I have an access control system with a linear power supply 230VAC/12VDC 5A that powers an electric bolt lock and an electric strike.
When the exit button is pushed it cuts the power from the electric bolt lock and it gives 12VDC to the electric strike. The power supply has a short circuit protection with a glass fuse but in the event of a stuck exit button the electric strike is fed with a constant 12VDC@2-3Amperes and eventually the coil (of the electric strike) just burns after some time.

I want to know how i can protect my electric strike from such an event. I am thinking of a PTC thermistor as a quick and easy way but how i choose one ?
Any other alternative ways ?

Comment: Are you trying to protect against accidental damage, or against someone trying to use that fault to defeat the security somehow?

Comment: The control should have a time delay coil driver to latch. The contacts should have a snubber to prevent premature failure.  a PTC would be too quick.

Comment: Sounds like you need a better exit button if it’s getting stuck.

Comment: Get a strike that doesn't overheat.